# Entering content in Document Library. Why do I only have the quick edit option

Tags: document-library

I notice in several libraries in the company a form is presented when uploading documents, yet for the libraries I've created, I only have the quick edit option.  I would like the form so that I can provide Help tips next to each required field.

Where is this setting managed?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean you only have the quick edit option? don't you have `Upload Document` option under `FILES` option in top ribbon?

Comment: Maybe you are using datasheet view in your library. is that so?

Comment: Yes.  I'm looking at the documents in the document library.  It's presented as a list.. each doc on a row with column name across the top.  I upload and the document appears at the top of the list.

Comment: can you please attach the screenshot if possible?

Comment: I should have mentioned, I'm using SharePoint Online, Modern Experience.

Comment: in Modern experience, you will not get the form while uploading document. however you can exit the modern experience and use in classic experience.

Answer (score 0):

under the list tab ribbon of the page, you should have a few different options available, including Quick edit (View Format section), create view (Manage Views), and a customized list section that has multiple edit options from customize form to New quick step. you should also have  a List Settings option under the settings section. Are these not available to you?

[image: List ribbon]